# in deploying my express js api i encountered "Your Team encountered an unknown problem. Please reach out to our support team for details. Learn More"

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, vercel

When I was attempting to deploy my Express.js API on Vercel, I encountered the following error:

```
 Your Team encountered an unknown problem. Please reach out to our support team for details. Learn More
```

Can you help me with this?

Notice I have tried the deployment as it says in the following
https://vercel.com/guides/using-express-with-vercel

Comment: You're here on Stackoverflow, not on Vercel. Why don't you ask Vercel, when they tell you to do so?

Answer (score 0):

1. Verify Email Configuration in GitHub and Vercel: Make sure the
   primary email address used in GitHub is the same as the one
   registered with your Vercel account. This consistency helps in
   avoiding authentication or permission issues during deployment.
2. Check for Email Verification: Ensure that all emails associated with
   your GitHub and Vercel accounts are verified. Unverified emails can
   sometimes cause unexpected issues.
3. Use a Single Primary Email for Deployments: If possible, stick to
   one primary email address for both GitHub and Vercel. This reduces
   the complexity and potential misconfigurations that might arise from
   using multiple emails.
4. Review GitHub-Vercel Integration Settings: In your Vercel account,
   review the settings for the GitHub integration. Ensure that the
   permissions and repository access configurations are correctly set
   up.

Comment: when I tried the Pro Version it has worked. even if after the expiry of the Pro.